# What is a polite way to ask "What breed is your pet dog? Or what kind of mixture if he's a mixture?"

Tags: dogs, breeds

When someone tells me they have got a pet dog, I am always interested in what kind, whether that means which breed, or what overall group (terrier, sheepdog), or what mixture if he is a mixture. But there is a danger of offending people, of conveying an impression of snobbery (with "What breed is he?"), perhaps with condescension (with "What breed is he? Or what mix, if he's a mix?").

What is a polite and respectful way to ask?

Comment: This question is obviously about pets, and there is nothing in the material published at the help centre that suggests that it is anything other than fully on-topic. But since a moderator has chosen to put it on hold claiming the contrary without a detailed source, I will delete it and my account.

Comment: This isn't about pets, it's about Interpersonal Skills (communication) and might be a better fit over here: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way to ask what kind of dog someone owns is to ask exactly that, ie:

> 'Oh, you have a dog? What kind?' (or 'What kind is he/she?' if you know the sex.)

If you ask what 'kind' of dog it is you're not seen to be asking specifically about breed, pedigree, or anything like that. That way the owner can just as easily say 'he's a pure-bred Irish Wolfhound. Cost me an arm and a leg and eats like a sumo wrestler, but I love him' as 'she's just a mix I got from the pound. I don't know what's in her, but I just had to have her!'

Comment: This is probably the right answer to the question. Before accepting it, I will wait a bit to find out whether anyone has any other advice. The only thing I'd be worried about is that when I ask "What kind?" I might get an answer such as "Barky" or "Placid", not because the person has misunderstood but because they want to be irritatingly pedantic. I kind of have this tendency to want to be exactly correct and to guard against the possibility that I am chatting with such a person, a tendency that perhaps I should sit on because most people aren't like that.

Comment: @ruffle As a dog owner myself and regular dog park attendee, I've never heard a snarky response to "what kind". If you're meeting a dog in person, it's common to get "Is s/he a ___?" (people frequently ask if our mini American Eskimo is a Pomeranian, for example). In either form it's a very ordinary question and a common way to show interest in the other person's dog.

Comment: True - being specific can break the ice: "Is she a beardie?", "Is he a Yorkie or an Australian Silky?" My ex-wife once asked a man who had 3 loud spitz-type dogs in the back of his car, possibly Alaskan Malamutes, "What kind of dogs are they?" and he replied in a "What a stupid question" tone that they were chihuahuas. Sadly this rudeness sticks in the mind more than the countless times walking a dog in parks or the countryside when other dog walkers have been  keen to converse about dogs in a mutually respectful way. "What kind?" is indeed a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @ruffle If someone's determined to be rude, no way of phrasing the question will stop them from being rude. I've never had any issue with "Oh, what a beautiful dog! Can I ask what (he/she) is?"

Answer (score 0):

I have a high end Labrador Retriever and mutt from rescue.  I am happy to tell either.

Not the question but ask if you can pet.